# Unable to cast TransparentProxy to SelectElement in Selenium

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to cast `IWebElement` to `SelectElement` in a Selenium script like following:

```
 SelectElement selectCalendar = (SelectElement)orderPage.CalendarType;
```

... but I get prompted with the following error:
`System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement'`.

I don't know what this error means. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly typecasting it should be

```
SelectElement selectCalendar = new SelectElement(orderPage.CalendarType);
```

this will solve above problem